# JScrollBar Resize for Drawings

Tags: java, swing, scrollbar

Im trying to make a drawing that has a lot of elements and they dont all fit the height of the screen. So i decided to use a scrollbar to allow my elements to be drawn and the user just has to scroll down. However, the scrollbar doesnt scroll even though the elements keep drawing. I tried setting the preferred size but then the scrollbar never readjusted based on the number of drawing. Is there anyway to dynamically resize the scrollbar:

```
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    drawBus(3, g);
    drawDff(g, 4);
    for(int a = 0; a<35; a++){
    drawAndGate("!AB!CD", g, a);
    this.setPreferredSize(screenSize);
    }
}


 public void drawAndGate(String input , Graphics orGfx, int numFF){
            orGfx.setColor(Color.black);
            orGfx.drawLine(400, 50 + (numFF*40), 400, 80 + (numFF*40));
            orGfx.drawLine(400, 50 + (numFF*40),420, 50 + (numFF*40));
            orGfx.drawLine(400, 80 + (numFF*40),420, 80 + (numFF*40));
            orGfx.drawArc(400, 50 + (numFF*40), 40,30, 270,180);
            orGfx.drawLine(400, 50 + (numFF*40) + 20, 0, 50 + ((numFF*40) +    20));
            orGfx.drawString(input, 400 - (input.length()*10), 50 + (numFF*40)+15);
            for(int a = 0; a < input.length(); a++){
                if(input.charAt(a) == '!'){                    
                    orGfx.fillOval((40 * 2*((int)input.charAt(a+1) - 64) - 5),50 + (numFF*40) + 15,10,10);
                    System.out.println((int)input.charAt(a+1) - 64);
                    a = a + 1;
                }
                else{
                orGfx.fillOval(40 + (40 *((int)input.charAt(a) - 64) - 5),50 + (numFF*40) + 15,10,10);
                }

            }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    draw3 d = new draw3(Color.white);
    d.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,800));
    JScrollPane  sg = new JScrollPane(d,VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    JFrame j = new JFrame();
    j.setBackground(Color.white);
    j.setSize(400, 400);
    j.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    j.add(sg);
    j.setTitle("Circuit");
    j.pack();
    j.setVisible(true);
    j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Swing doesn't really accept the sizes of compenents sometimes. this is because most layout managers just ignore them. I would suggest trying other layoutmanagers in the viewport, but I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't make it clear where you're drawing the elements, but I'm assuming it is in `d`. Make sure it extends `JPanel` and set `sg`'s preferredSize, not `d`'s, since it would limit it's space for the elements and there would be no scrolling.

Also, it will only scroll if the drawings occupy space as `Components`, so putting each one in a `JLabel` or `JPanel` would be better.

Ps.: If you are adding the drawings dynamically you should use `invokeLater()` from `SwingUtilities`, to make sure you're synced with Swing's Thread. Otherwise, you'll need to call `revalidate()` every time you make a drawing.

Comment: i tried setting the preferredsize of sg but then it didnt scroll, it only scrols when i set the size for the panel? And could you explain what you mean by making my drawings  occupy space as a component?

Comment: The panel will occupy the necessary space for its contents to fit in as long as you have a `LayoutManager` (I never tried using `JScrollPane` without one), so you don't need to set it's size, and the displayable area will be `sg`'s `preferredSize`. By "occupy space as `Components`" I meant that you should place each drawing inside a `JPanel` or `JLabel`, since they occupy space and then `sg` will know that `d` is bigger than the displayed area, making scrolling available.